# MS Word - document protection

Tags: ms-word, openssl, docx

I generate docx files as output from my tool. I would like to add document protection into docx.
According to ECMA-376 specification, I want to use SHA-1 encryption. The sample for "test" password and "foo" salt is:

```
    <w:documentProtection 
    w:enforcement="1"
    w:edit="forms" 
    w:cryptProviderType="rsaFull"
    w:cryptAlgorithmClass="hash"
    w:cryptAlgorithmType="typeAny"
    w:cryptAlgorithmSid="4"
    w:cryptSpinCount="1"
    w:hash="uPlhSA7DpYSaAKL6AjGwy2MQfHs="
    w:salt="Zm9v">
```

w:hash was generated by command:`$ echo -n footest | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64`

w:salt was generated by command: `$ echo -n foo | base64`

This sample is the only output which is able to force MS Word 2010 to ask user for a password. But it doesn't accept "test" as password. What am I doing wrong ?

There is also a strange thing. If w:cryptSpinCount or w:salt is omitted, MS Word doesn't even ask for password. It seems to be a bug, as specification says that those attributes are optional.

I have also tried to use w:cryptSpinCount="0" without no effect.

Thank you for any help,
Pavel

Comment: I don't know, but does this article help you at all? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/05/how-to-set-the-editing-restrictions-in-word-using-open-xml-sdk-2-0.aspx

Comment: Cindy, thank you very much. The code from the article works perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) I don't understand enough about the topic to summarize the content of the blog article into an Answer, to go with the link. Would you be able to do that, with a code sample? You're allowed to Answer your own questions on StackOverflow, and mark them as "the" answer. This will be a great help to others who run into the same problem, in the future.